SwiftUI Error: Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context
Sample Code:
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var viewModel = ContentViewModel() // Compiler Error: "Call to main actor-isolated initializer 'init()' in a synchronous nonisolated context"
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World")
    }
}

@Observable
@MainActor
class ContentViewModel {
    // some properties here..
}

What is the best way to fix this issue? I think I can mark ContentView with MainActor, but is it a good practice and best way to solve it?

You can mark init of ContentViewModel as nonisolated

@State is designed for values or structs not classes because it will leak them try changing it to a struct.

@malhal no you are wrong, I think Apple told us to use @State for both struct and class for iOS 17+. See this link: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

@ShuaiqingLuo if you look closely you'll see they declared the @State in the App struct not a View. App is only init once so it's ok there, it would be better as a let though. It is not safe to use @State with class in a View however because it will leak, as I said.

You would be better off learning the View, State and Binding for your view model as its designed to work, instead of classes. Going on your own will lead to all kinds of issues.

Why will it leak? And I am pretty sure we can use @State with class....

It leaks because the State property wrapper inits it's initial value every time the View is re-init. This isn't a problem with values on the memory stack but objects being constantly init on the heap is something you'd want to avoid. Here is a forum link about it https://forums.developer.apple.com/forums/thread/736110

Add MainActor to the View
@MainActor
struct ContentView: View

This will be the standard in iOS 18+/Swift 6, the View already runs on the main actor by inheritance. It is just a formality.

If ContentView itself is already on MainActor for iOS 18+, why do I still need to mark it with @MainActor?

@ShuaiqingLuo because you are targeting less than that now. So the initializer for the model assumes nonisolated.

I think the init is assumed to be isolated

@ShuaiqingLuo if it did you wouldn’t get the warning. Only the body is attached to the main actor in older versions.

Are we talking about the same thing? I was saying the init of ContentViewModel is isolated, and changing it to be nonIsolated fixed the issue

@ShuaiqingLuo I was talking about the View’s.  Changing the model to nonisolated is just introducing a concurrency issue, it isn’t a fix just a workaround that will have to be undone eventually.
